# Subscribe to a characteristic and catch the value Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, subscription, descriptor, characteristics

I´m developing an BLE app, based on the Gatt sample project provided by google: https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/index.html. So, I can send data writing in a characteristic successfully. Now I need to know when this characteristic change its value.

**DeviceActivity**

```
private void displayGattServices(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices) 
{
   // get services & characteristics
   ................ 

final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = mGattCharacteristics.get(2).get(0);
        final int charaProp = characteristic.getProperties();
        mWriteCharacteristic = characteristic;
        mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(mWriteCharacteristic, true);

   // write in the characteristic to send a reset command to BLE device

   // Start the read method, that permit subscribe to the characteristic
   BluetoothLeService.read(mWriteCharacteristic);
   BluetoothLeService.set(mWriteCharacteristic,true);
};
```

**BluetoothLeService**

```
public static void read(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) 
     {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) 
        {
            Log.w("BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        };

        mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
    };

    public static void set(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean enabled) 
    {
        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) 
        {
            Log.w("BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        };

        mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);

        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(uuid);
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
    };
```

But I dont know how can I catch the value of the read characteristic. Actually, I dont know if my code subscribe succesful to the characteristic or not. Some one can help me? How can I check if the value of the characteristic change really? And how can I display the new value of this characteristic in the screen? Is correct my code or I need add, modify or remove something?
Thaks in advance.
I guide by this question: [Reading multiple characteristics from a BLE device synchronously (Recommended Method for Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855501/reading-multiple-characteristics-from-a-ble-device-synchronously-recommended-me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run a loop inside this function - **displayGattServices(List gattServices)** and get the entire services and characteristics of your connected BLE device.

For determining **characteristics name** and **properties** based on the UUID value you can refer to [BLE characteristics](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicsHome.aspx)

Once you have determined which characteristics is applicable for your BLE device, add it in a Queue and read/set them.

@ your **DeviceActivity** class

```
List <BluetoothGattCharacteristic> bluetoothGattCharacteristic = new ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();
Queue<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> mWriteCharacteristic = new LinkedList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();

private void displayGattServices(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices) 
{
    for(BluetoothGattService service : gattServices) 
    {   
        Log.i(TAG, "Service UUID = " + service.getUuid());

        bluetoothGattCharacteristic = service.getCharacteristics();

        for(BluetoothGattCharacteristic character: bluetoothGattCharacteristic)
        {   
            Log.i(TAG, "Service Character UUID = " + character.getUuid());    

            // Add your **preferred characteristic** in a Queue
            mWriteCharacteristic.add(character);   
        }
    }

    if(mWriteCharacteristic.size() > 0)
    {
       read_Characteristic();
    };
};
```

Add the below function also in your **DeviceActivity** class,

```
   // make sure this method is called when there is more than one characteristic to read & set
   private void read_Characteristic()  
   {

      BluetoothLeService.read(mWriteCharacteristic.element());
      BluetoothLeService.set(mWriteCharacteristic.element(),true);
      mWriteCharacteristic.remove();
   };
```

After setting them in your Service method, you need to have a broadcast receiver in your **DeviceActivity** activity class to handle the various events fired by your **BluetoothLeService** service class.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver gattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
{
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
   {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       final String action = intent.getAction();

       if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) 
       {
           // Connection with the BLE device successful                
           ................
           ................ 
       } 
       else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) 
       {
          // BLE device is disconnected 
          ................
          ................ 
       }
       else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) 
       {
          displayGattServices(BluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());
       }
       else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) 
       {
          Log.i(TAG, "Collecting data");

         ................
         ................

         // If there are more than one characteristic call this method again
         if(mWriteCharacteristic.size() > 0)
         {
            read_Characteristic();
         };
      };
   };  
};
```

If you further need an example code to guide you through, you can refer to [BLE sample code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/7167a054a8027f75025c865322fa84791a9b3bd1/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/src/com/example/bluetooth/le?autodive=0%2F)