# How to get the correct battery percentage from BLE devices

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, batterylevel

I am developing a small application , in this i have to show the ***battery percentage*** of **bluetooth low energy** device. Can any one please help me with this

Comment: Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539535/how-to-get-the-battery-level-after-connect-to-the-ble-device/19701412

Comment: go with @Ankita link if you need more help refer below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076353/how-to-update-the-battery-level-for-every-5seconds-in-ble-in-android