# How to write data to BLE device in android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am able to scan a ble device from my android application after this I want to send data to that scanned device. How to do? Kindly share me example code if any one have.

I referred to answered some one asked same question here [[Working with BLE Android 4.3 how to write characteristics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043388/working-with-ble-android-4-3-how-to-write-charactaristics][1])

but  am not getting below piace of code

```
 BluetoothGattService Service = mBluetoothGatt.getService(your Services);

Here what is `your seervice`

BluetoothGattCharacteristic charac = Service
            .getCharacteristic(your characteristic);

  Here what is `your characteristic`
```

Kindly explain above code

Thanks

Comment: did you tried examples from github which are available?? if not yet than please go through gihub which will give you extensive no of examples!!

Comment: Thanks for ur rply , can you share me link@JiteshUpadhyay

Answer (score 0):

To understand about services and characteristic, ddl and run the official BLE projet : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/cefd49aae65dc85161d08419494071d74ffb982f/samples/BluetoothLeGatt

Your device contains many services which describe what it can offer to you. With the official projet you can have access to them. Note that each services is like : 
0000XXXX-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34f
you can find the XXXX here :https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx
And it is the same for the characteristic

For example if you want to find the name of the device
Service UUID code is 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34f and the characteristic is  Device name. UUID 00002A00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34f.

To answer you, your services is an UUID.